# Magento: how to display the correct images for configurable products in search results

Tags: magento

I'm building configurable products on my Magento site (a simple way of showing each of our textiles with the swatches of the different colors of the same item under the main product image) and I have associated simple products for each individual color.
I don't seem to be able to obtain the desired behavior from the site and I'm writing to ask if you have a suggestion that might solve my problem.
At the moment I experience this behavior: when filtering products through color-level attributes I get both the simple and configurable products in my result set. Once I do that if I click on a simple product I find myself the simple product detail page, which doesn't show the box with the other color swatches.. while I would like every product detail page to show the other colors of the same item.

The intended usage is very basic really but I can't figure out if Magento can achieve that on its own or if it will require extra code; what I need is:

1) all product detail pages to show all the color swatches
2) the result list when filtering by the color attribute (for example "whites") should show the correct color images of the individual colors, without duplicates (and not the main image for that product, which would probably be in the wrong color)

Do you have a suggestion of maybe know of a plugin to achieve this?
Thanks a lot,
Sergio

Answer (score 0):

Sergio,
     There are two features in particular that might help you solve your problem.

First:

Click to expand the Shopping Cart section. Then, set Configurable Product Image to one
of the following:
l Product Thumbnail Itself
l Parent Product Thumbnail

Second:

To prevent the associated products from being listed individually in the catalog, set Visibility to “Not Visible Individually.”  Or in your case, you may decide to do it the other way around.

Please be aware that I was not able to get this feature to work myself.